# How to make a utility function available to all components

Tags: reactjs, function, global

Assume that you have written a function that is needed by all components.

How can this be made available to everything, without an `import` in every component?

In other words, how can I basically make a function global?

Example: I need this lovely `logState` function available in every component:

```
const logState = (s) => {
    console.log("Current state")
    console.dir(s)
}
```

How can I do this without storing in a file (say, `util.js`) and importing in every component, like so?

```
export const logState = (s) => {
    console.log("Current state")
    console.dir(s)
}
```

Import and usage:

```
import logState from './util.js'

logState({"status":"good"})
```

I suppose that I could create a global `window.util` object, and then:

```
window.util.logState = (s) => {
    console.log("Current state")
    console.dir(s)
}

window.util.logState({"status":"good"})
```

..but this is not so beautiful.

Comment: What's wrong with importing a function where you need it?

Comment: Why not pass it as a prop down to child components from your root component, and have these child functions pass their props by means of `{...props}` with whatever else they need set?  Then it's universally available as `this.props.thing()`, so the function is passed everywhere, without specifying that it is so.

Comment: Making it a global is far worse than just "not so beautiful". The only excuse for a global in modular environment is that it cannot be  shared in another way  with a context where it's consumed, which is not true in this case. Use a proper IDE. The problem is nonexistent with auto-imports.